# awsv2 sso login does not open the default browser on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sso

For some reason, when I ran `awsv2 sso login`, the default browser window does not open. Instead, the cli prompts

```
 Attempting to automatically open the SSO authorization page in your 
 default browser. If the browser does not open or you wish to use 
 a different device to authorize this request, open the following URL:
```

I have to open a browser window manually, and copy-paste the code to finish the single sign on. I am using awscliv2 2.2.0.

```
% awsv2 --version
2.2.0

CLI version: aws-cli/2.13.31 Python/3.11.6 Linux/6.3.13-linuxkit docker/aarch64.amzn.2
```